# Only show mobile app banner for iOS and Android

Tags: bug, mobile-web, mobile-app

I'm using a Windows Phone. When I viewed a question, I got a banner about downloading an app instead. However, at the bottom of the page, there are only notifications for iOS and Android. Tapping the banner was, as expected, totally ineffective.

If there's no app for Windows Phone, fine, but can you at least only show the banner for people who actually *can* use the app?

Comment: Your edit was incorrect- what about other platforms like Tizen or Blackberry? Windows Phone isn't the only one.

Comment: Looking into this, the banner is supposed to only show for iOS and android. Mind giving a bit more info? What browser and what version of the OS are you running?

Comment: @KasraRahjerdi, I have added my information to the question (I am having the same issue).  Can you look into this again?

Comment: Update: My edit got rejected and I was told to post this as an answer... So I did.

Answer (score 2):

I have this same issue.  I am using an HTC One(M8)(Windows Phone version) using the default browser, IE.  The default user agent is

```
Mozilla/5.0 (Mobile; Windows Phone 8.1; Android 4.0; ARM; Trident/7.0; Touch; rv:11.0; IEMobile/11.0; HTC; HTC6995LVW) like iPhone OS 7_0_3 Mac OS X AppleWebKit/537 (KHTML, like Gecko) Mobile Safari/537
```

Unsurprisingly, I can recreate this using Firefox on my desktop using this user agent.  If I use the following user agent, the site is displayed as mobile, without the banner:

```
Mozilla/5.0 (Mobile; Windows Phone 8.1; ARM; Trident/7.0; Touch; rv:11.0; IEMobile/11.0; HTC; HTC6995LVW)
```

Note I removed the `Android 4.0` and the `like iPhone...` sections.  It appears that removing either is insufficient, but removing both removes the banner.

However, changing the user agent on my phone is either difficult or impossible, so if this could still be looked into, that would be great!